# compare two array elements with conditions in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents as

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "base": 23,
        "dateValues": [{
            "timestamp": "2021-02-15T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-22T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "base": 256,
        "dateValues": [{
            "timestamp": "2021-02-01T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-10T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "base": 256,
        "dateValues": [{
            "timestamp": "2021-02-03T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-04T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-10T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "base": 256,
        "dateValues": [{
            "timestamp": "2021-02-03T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }, {
            "timestamp": "2021-02-08T13:13:17.611Z",
            "value": 50
        }]
    }
]
```

Now I want to compare dates of all objects. I'll simplify the logic as simply as I can step wise..

1. First I want to get all the distinct set of dates so these will be

```
"2021-02-01"
"2021-02-03"
"2021-02-04"
"2021-02-08"
"2021-02-15"
"2021-02-22"
"2021-02-10"
```

2. Now I want to loop above dates and compare each date with each objects dateValues

For example if we take first date "2021-02-01", I want only one date from each object(document)

- who are less than or equal to "2021-02-01"
- whose timestamp is latest timestamp
- If no dateValue found then we take base value
- Finally we will sum these values

so for this date **"2021-02-01"** dateValues will be

```
for id 1 no date value is there so in this case I need to take base value, which is 23
for id 2 we found date value so we will take its corresponding value, which is 50
for id 3 and 4 no date is matching so again we are taking its base value which 256 and 256
so final value comes for date "2021-02-01" is 23+50+256+256 = 585
```

Just another example for date **"2021-02-22"**

```
for id 1 we found date "2021-02-22", value is 50
for id 2 we found date "2021-02-10" value is 50
for id 3 we found date "2021-02-10" value is 50
for id 4 we found date "2021-02-08" value is 50
Final value for date "2021-02-22" is 200
```

Can we do this logic in mongo db aggregations?
I could only get distinct dates but after that I lost it. Can anyone help me with this mongodb aggregation? or is it even possible to implement this logic in mongodb aggregation?

Answer (score 2):

Mongo aggregation framework has a **lot** of powerful operators and it basically boils down to chaining the stages and operators in correct order.

Assuming you have the documents in a collection named `st`.

Explanation:

- Unwind and Group will give you one document for each date
- Lookup all the documents in the same collection for each date
- Apply the pipeline inside lookup to all documents during lookup finding the dateValue that matches the date or returning the base.
- Sum the records

```
[
    { $unwind: "$dateValues" },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$dateValues.timestamp"
    }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: "st",
        as: "records",
        let: { date: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
            { $project: {
                base: 1,
                dateValues: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$dateValues",
                        as: "dateValue",
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$dateValue.timestamp", "$$date"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }},
            { $project: {
                val: { $cond: {
                    if: {$eq: [ {$size: "$dateValues"}, 1]},
                    then: "$dateValues.0.value",
                    else: "$base"
                }}
            }},
        ],
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        finalValue: {
            $sum: "$records.val"
        }
    }}
]
```

Results:

```
{ "_id" : "2021-02-22T13:13:17.611Z", "finalValue" : 768 }
{ "_id" : "2021-02-01T13:13:17.611Z", "finalValue" : 535 }
{ "_id" : "2021-02-15T13:13:17.611Z", "finalValue" : 768 }
{ "_id" : "2021-02-04T13:13:17.611Z", "finalValue" : 535 }
{ "_id" : "2021-02-10T13:13:17.611Z", "finalValue" : 279 }
{ "_id" : "2021-02-03T13:13:17.611Z", "finalValue" : 279 }
{ "_id" : "2021-02-08T13:13:17.611Z", "finalValue" : 535 }
```

Note: Please double check the `$filter` and `$cond` and ensure that it matches your requirements.

Updated pipeline:
Added a reduce stage

- The filter stage selects all the `dateValues` with timestamp <= the date.
- The reduce stage selects the largest `dateValue` amongst them.

```
[
        { $unwind: "$dateValues" },
        { $group: {
            _id: "$dateValues.timestamp"
        }},
        { $lookup: {
            from: "st",
            as: "records",
            let: { date: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $project: {
                    base: 1,
                    dateValues: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$dateValues",
                            as: "dateValue",
                            cond: { $lte: ["$$dateValue.timestamp", "$$date"] },
                        }
                    }
                }},
                { $project: {
                    base: 1,
                    dateValues: {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$dateValues",
                            initialValue: null,
                                in: { $cond: {
                                    if: { $gt: ["$$this.timestamp", "$$value.timestamp"] },
                                    then: "$$this",
                                    else: "$$value"
                                }}
                        }
                    }
                }},
                { $project: {
                    val: { $cond: {
                        if: {$eq: ["$dateValues", null]},
                        then: "$base",
                        else: "$dateValues.value",
                    }}
                }},
            ],
        }},
        { $project: {
            _id: 1,
            finalValue: {
                $sum: "$records.val"
            }
        }}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ramit.. Really appreciated :)  I tried this but Its not taking latest date. I mean if we are taking date  "2021-02-22" in comparison it should take date which is less than equal and it should have latest timestamp. Currently we are just taking first array element. I tried sorting array and grouping it back but then sum is not happening correctly..

Comment: Im sorry but dates are coming same after comparing and also "val" is getting overwritten by last object so calculations for "val" is same for all.